# Descartes lemma proof

Tags: calculus

I need to prove the following by induction, but I don't know how. Can someone give me some hints.

$P(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ for $a_{n},a_{n-1},...,a_0\in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that, the number of positive roots of a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients does not exceed the number of sign changes of its coefficients. A zero coefficient is not counted as a sign change.

Comment: That is a consequence of "Descarte's rule of signs" which you can google. If you keep going on google likely you'll find a proof.

Comment: Thanks - but I have google it but did not find anything exactly for this statement. There were other theorems and lemma but not like this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs In the very first paragraph of this wiki article iw the tateement you want to show. You didn't seem to look much.

Comment: I saw this page but there is not any proof. There is only an example and I understand the statement but don't know how to prove it, but thank you. Maybe someone can give me a hint :)

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245067545_A_Simple_Proof_of_Descartes%27s_Rule_of_Signs  googled and got to this which apparantly has a PDF file containing a proof of the rule. Once you get there you have to follow up with some more clicking but I didn't try. I hope it doesn't eventually ask for money to read it, if so don't pay and sorry.

Comment: I saw a proof once but it was quite involved. I also would like to see a simple proof, thought above might be one. But I still think to prove it takes many steps (there isn't a proof in only a few lines).

Comment: Yes, as I understood it Descartes rule of sign does not have a simple proof, but the statement I write is just a smaller part of Descartes sign of rule, which could be proved with a simple induction proof and it is this proof I can not figure out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131703/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-sumi).